# Dragging items within ListBox/LongListSelector in a WinPhone Silverlight app

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

Many Windows Phone apps allows you to reorder items in their lists by dragging them. Here is an example from one of them, [Nokia App Folder](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/app-folder/7d2e7de3-95e7-4143-8a9d-aedf8c3f901e):

[image]

You can see a small drag icon next to every item one can use to reorder items.

I need to add this drag reorder functionality to some lists in my WP8 Silverlight apps. Can you suggest any idea of how it can be done for such standard list controls like ListBox or LongListSelector? A link to a good Internet article is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ReorderListBox

One of the first implementations I saw of this was on the MSDN blogs a couple of years ago by Jason Ginchereau...

[WP7 ReorderListBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/01/03/wp7-reorderlistbox-improvements-rearrange-animations-and-more.aspx)

Although it was originally for the WP7 `Listbox`, it should be possible to modify and use it for WP8's `LongListSelector`, which replaces the `ListBox`. As the article mentions, the source code is on [CodePlex](http://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/) or available as pre-built NuGet package.

### Drag Re-ordering

Colin Eberhardt also has a fantastic article on re-ordering items in a list...

[A gesture-driven Windows Phone To-do application part two - drag re-ordering](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/06/27/a-gesture-driven-windows-phone-todo-application-part-two-drag-re-ordering.html)

This approach doesn't use a `Listbox` or `LonglistSelector` but it is another great reference.

### Commercial option

If you have access to the Telerik Windows Phone controls, their `RadDataBoundListBox` has a built-in re-order feature although [it's implementation is a little different to the two mentioned above](http://blogs.telerik.com/windowsphoneteam/posts/12-06-20/introducing-item-reorder-in-raddataboundlistbox-for-windows-phone-video-included.aspx).